# How to manually send query notification using service broker?

Tags: sql-server, service-broker, query-notifications

according to limitations of query notification by using `SqlDependency`,

How can we send query notifications using service broker SEND statement in a way that .net `SqlDependency` can catch and parse it as a valid message it needs?

I mean something like this:

```
BEGIN DIALOG @conversation
FROM SERVICE SenderService
TO SERVICE N'SqlQueryNotificationService-8dc7e234-7e23-47ab-8d62-13e83a6ae262'
ON CONTRACT [http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/PostQueryNotification]
WITH ENCRYPTION=OFF;

--- Send the message
SEND ON CONVERSATION @conversation
MESSAGE TYPE [http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/QueryNotification]
(@msg);
```

what should be my `@msg` and `ENCRYPTION`?

Comment: The message structure is defined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189308.aspx)

Comment: thanks about the link. I saw the page but i'm confused. the message is shown there contains this `<qn:Message>http://mysite.microsoft.com/catalog.aspx?Category=Cars</qn:Message>` but it's not so for me!
i can see just a GUID inside the `<qn:Message>` tag.